# Remove duplicates from cfquery based on a particular column

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfquery

I have got two cfquery result with same column name. I want to merge them in such a way that I remove the duplicates based on a particular colum.

So it should be like merge query 1 with query 2 where value of query1.column1 > query2.column1

Is there a way to get this done by MS SQL?

My resulteset is like this at the moment

```
|name |value| temp_id
test1   1     001
test1   2         001
test2   2         002
test2   1         002
```

I want to get the rows with distinct column (name) and higest value

So from above example I want

test1 with value 2 and test 2 with value 2

Comment: If you are talking about merging a single column, use a `UNION`. Otherwise, can you post your two queries? Also, this expression `query1.column1 > query2.column1` implies something other than duplicate (equal) values. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only looking to get the name and the maximum value then you can just do

```
SELECT name, MAX(value) AS value
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Please look at the edits I made to my question. this should explain you better.

Comment: @nasaa - When you say "get the **rows** with distinct column (name) and highest value" do you want all columns in the query row `name,value,temp_id` or just `name, value`?

Comment: @Leigh - I want all the columns. Actually I have two result set from cfquery. Then I have to merge them which results in duplicate rows. Union does not help because one of the column is different in both the query. Now what I want is to get all the rows which have unique ID and  highest value in one of the two column. I will expand my question in a better way tomorrow when I am back to work.

Comment: @nasaa - Okay. Is using a QoQ a requirement? In all likelihood doing this within a database query will be more efficient. But we would need to know your database type and version.